# What is a fixed matrix?

Tags: matrices

I have seen the term "fixed matrix" being used in a lot of definitions. 
What does one mean when they say a "fixed" matrix? And what is this "fixed" property relative to?

EDIT: I was asked for an example so here it is:

Definition: Let **A** $\in\mathbb{R}^{mxn}$ be a fixed matrix

**A** : $\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$
$\iff x\mapsto $ **A**$x$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and **A**$x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$

Comment: I'd need more context to know for sure, but I'm guessing it means all of the entries are constants.  For example, $A=\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4}$ is a "fixed" matrix and $B(t) = \pmatrix{t^2+2  & 4 \\ t+1 & t}$ is a "variable" matrix.

Comment: "Fixed" for the ensuing discussion, in which other, arbitrary matrices will be referred to by other variables. If you can show an example we can be less terse too.

Comment: It may be a definitionof the following kind: **Definition.** Fix an object $A$ then for any object $X$ define $f(X)=g(A,X)$. -- This may just save you from having to mention $A$ throuighout when you are about to investigate it for the next couple of pages ...

Comment: Maybe just replace "fixed" with "given"